# Simple HTML DOM PHP web crawler not following links from initial crawled pages

Tags: php, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

I'm working on a PHP web crawler, using [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Here's my code:

```
<?php

include_once('simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');


$seeds = [
    'http://www.google.com/?q=web+development#q=web+development',
    'http://www.google.com/?q=art#q=art'
];

// Web crawl
function crawl($seeds) {
    foreach($seeds as $key) {
        $html = new simple_html_dom();
        $html->load_file($key);
        foreach ($html->find('a') as $link) {
            array_push($seeds, $link->href);
        }
    }
    $seeds = array_unique($seeds);
    print_r($seeds);
}

?>
```

The string `simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php` is the path to Simple HTML DOM. The problem is that it only crawls the initial 2 URLs in the `$seeds` array ('http://www.google.com/?q=web+development#q=web+development','http://www.google.com/?q=art#q=art'). But, I want it to crawl all of the URLs that the second `foreach` loop pushes to the array. How do I fix this?

Lastly, what is the best way to handle the increasing `$seeds` array? It will continually crawl without stopping, so I want to keep track of all of the URLs. Should I write it to a file, or is my best option to simply stop it after so long (what is the best way to do this?)? I need to be able to work with the array either in another PHP file also running on the server or from the same PHP file in parallel.

Comment: I suspect if you want to crawl anything that Google returns, you'll need to make your function recursive (i.e. so it calls itself with new seeds). In terms of the broader "how to", it can be quite a big undertaking to manage all of your seed links effectively. Might it be better to start with [an existing, working crawler](http://www.seekquarry.com/)?